# Adding default value for Atrribute in xsd file

Tags: xml, xsd

i know that i can set default ad fixes values for attributes. But I want following :

I have a complex type named optiontype.

```
<xs:complexType name="optiontype">
    <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:extension base="xs:string">
            <xs:attribute ref="base:valuetype" use="required"></xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:normalizedString" use="required"></xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="default" type="xs:normalizedString"></xs:attribute>
            <xs:attribute name="comment" type="xs:normalizedString" use="optional"></xs:attribute>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

I use this type many times like this one :

```
<xs:complexType name="servicesettingstype">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Element für die Service Einstellungen</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="option" type="base:optiontype"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="option" type="base:optiontype"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

It is possible to set a default value for the Attribute name in the type servicesettings type ?

Like :

```
<xs:complexType name="servicesettingstype">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Element für die Service Einstellungen</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="option" type="base:optiontype" optiontype:name="Settings1"></xs:element>
        <xs:element name="option" type="base:optiontype" optiontype:name="Settings2"></xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot do that, neither you can give a default value to a required attribute, so I don't think that is possible.